# Captcha required using my static IP address

Tags: networking, router, ip, spam-prevention, captcha

Everytime I open one of many websites, I have to pass the captcha challenge, I have a static IP address for my Sisco 1900 series fiber optics connection, and another static IP address for the ADSL connection. When I use the fiber with any PC I get this screen, with the ADSL in the same PCs I pass normally. So the problem seems to be related to my fiber IP address.

What could be the cause? and how to solve it?

I scanned my PC with different AV software (Avira, Kaspersky, Malwarebytes...) and everything seems clean.

[image]

Comment: What is the cause, you are triggering the spam prevention on this websites, for the exact reason for each website I suggest contacting the support for those websites.  How do you solve it: By contacting the support for those websites.

Comment: What makes you believe that the CAPTCHA should behave differently just because you have a static IP? If the site recorded bad actors on that IP 2 years ago (before you got it), or is coming from a AS the admin decided is untrustworthy,  it is completely up to them how they handle the CAPTCHA requirement. I'm not sure why you believe that CAPTCHA would be universally bypassed by having a static IP. Static vs Dynamic IPs are only a concern of the client and the server dishing them out. From an upstream perspective every IP is a static address.

Comment: @Ramhound I think it's not related to those individual websites, I think it's related to maybe a spam/ddos prevention service from CloudFlare as in the bottom of the screenshot

Comment: well, that message is indicating that the site believes your network is dishing out malware. Its likely that the network your fiber connection is on or routes through to reach the affected server has been blacklisted by cloudflare.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes seems possible. I found a video on how to resolve this using projecthoneypot, I submitted a whitelisting request and hoping not to get blacklisted again